# Render controller, don't work Ajax;

Tags: ajax, symfony

I'm cut all the logic from main controller with Ajax Search, put it in a custom controller and render it in my template:

```
{{render(controller('MainBundle:SearchCertificate:searchCertificate'))}}
```

But the Ajax doesn't work.

I have an Ajax request in my symfony toolbar(when submitting form) as follows:

> POST  xhr 200 /app_dev.php/main/order/create  820ms   14f184

I set breakpoints (in php code), but PHPStorm skip them (no result).

Comment: so when you click on the ajax request in the profiler, what does it tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, i forgot create routing for my new Controller.
And change url in Ajax(`url: "{{ path('app.admin.search.certificate')}}"`)

router:

```
app.admin.search.certificate:
   path: /admin/serach-certificate
   defaults: { _controller: MainBundle:SearchCertificate:searchCertificate }
```

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ path('app.admin.search.certificate')}}",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('#form_search_certificate').serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        $("#search_result").empty();
        var dataParse = JSON.parse(data.result_search);
        if (dataParse.length !== 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dataParse.length; i++) {
                $.tmpl(template, {
                    "id": dataParse[i].id,
                    "dpId": dataParse[i].dp_id,
                    "name": dataParse[i].name,
                    "price": dataParse[i].price,
                    "discount": dataParse[i].discount.value,
                    "description": dataParse[i].description,
                    "image": dataParse[i].image,
                    "companyName": dataParse[i].company.name,
                    "categoryName": dataParse[i].category.name,
                    "cart_id": data.cart_id
                }).appendTo("#search_result");
            }
        } else {
            $.tmpl(empty, {}).appendTo("#search_result");
        }
    }});
```